# A Rating Formula that Combines Two Metrics

Tags: rating

If I have two metrics, - number of reviews and the rating out of 5, and I want to combine them into a single meaningful rating that can rank a list, how can I do that?

For example, let's say I have the following:

```
BeachName-#Reviews-Rating

Pantai Kaneko Beach-10-4.9 (meaning 10 reviews with a rating of 4.9)

Pantai Kelating Beach-517-4.4

Pantai Pusat Beach-913-4.5

Pantai Abian Kepas Beach-156-4.4

Pantai Antap Beach-177-4.6

Pantai Manyar Beach-141-4.3

Pantai Pernama Beach-840-4.3

Pantai Saba Beach-102-4.4

Pantai Masceti Beach-1155-4.4

Pantai Cucukan Beach-1-4

Emerald Dive Spot-2-5

USAT Liberty Shipwreck-896-4.7

Pantai Nusantara Beach-62-4.1

Menjangan Island-137-4.6
```

I don't have more than grade 5 maths. What Excel formula could I use to combine these two numbers to rank this list by popularity. I want to do more than say this beach has the most reviews....I would like to adjust that by the review out of five to try and get a better ranking.

Comment: Do you have access to the original ratings, or only to the summaries (mean and number of ratings)? [Here is a recommendation](https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) that works if you only have "positive" and "negative" ratings - if you have the original 1-5 ratings, you could in principle do something similar. With the summary alone, it will be a bit harder.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I only have access to the number of reviews and the mean rating....Is there anything meaningful I can do with that data?